# Delete or Ignore a line from CSV - Python

Tags: python, csv, file, hyperlink

I try to find a way to add a function in my script to ignore or delete the first line of my CSV files. I know we can do that with pandas but it is possible without?

Many thanks for your help.

Here is my code -

```
from os import mkdir
from os.path import join, splitext, isdir
from glob import iglob
from csv import DictReader
from collections import defaultdict
from urllib.request import urlopen
from shutil import copyfileobj

csv_folder = r"/Users/folder/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/CSVfiles/"
glob_pattern = "*.csv"
for file in iglob(join(csv_folder, glob_pattern)):
    with open(file) as csv_file:
        reader = DictReader(csv_file)
        save_folder, _ = splitext(file)
        if not isdir(save_folder):
            mkdir(save_folder)
        title_counter = defaultdict(int)
        for row in reader:
            url = row["link"]
            title = row["title"]
            title_counter[title] += 1
            _, ext = splitext(url)
            save_filename = join(save_folder, f"{title}_{title_counter[title]}{ext}".replace('/', '-'))
            print(f"'{save_filename}'")
            with urlopen(url) as req, open(save_filename, "wb") as save_file:
                copyfileobj(req, save_file)
```

Comment: If you don't need pandas, please don't include that tag.

Comment: If my answer resolved your issue, please accept the answer so others know it works. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `next()` function to skip the first row of your CSV.

```
with open(file) as csv_file:
    reader = DictReader(csv_file)

    # skip first row
    next(reader)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could just read the raw text from the file as normal and then split the text by new line and delete the first line:

```py
file = open(filename, 'r')   # Open the file
content = file.read()        # Read the file
lines = content.split("\n")  # Split the text by the newline character
del lines[0]                 # Delete the first index from the resulting list, ie delete the first line.
```

Although this may take a long time for larger CSV files, so this may not be the best solution.

Or you could simply skip the first row in your for loop.
Instead of:

```py
...
for row in reader:
...
```

Could you use:

```py
...
for row_num, row in enumerate(list(reader)):
    if row_num == 0:
        continue
    ...
```

instead? I think that should skip the first row.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, not sure how I can implement this in my code. I need to keep this code like this as it works correctly, just need to add a way to ignore the first line of my CSV files when read.

Comment: Any thoughts on my edit?

Comment: Seems working but strangely my script stops after the first CSV and don't continue to process all others CSV in my folder.

Comment: @bigbox and Nathcat, I suggest *always* using the CSV module to read CSV files because a row does not always equal a line. Anyways, once you have a reader, just call ‘next(reader)’ to step over the first row and then do your ‘for row in reader:’ loop.

Comment: Hi @ZachYoung , thank you for your suggestion, it's not totally clear for me sorry.

Comment: What CaptainCaveman is showing.